# Google Appscript partial vlookup

Tags: google-apps-script

I am very new to appscript and any help on the below query will really be helpful.

I am having data in Sheet1 in column A and Column B, now I want to design an appscript which get the below job done.

(1) Sheet1 Column A has Roll number along with student name i.e. Roll No.*Name, column B has actual value (these both columns are user input).

(2) Sheet2 has two columns Roll No. and Dummy value.

(3) In Sheet1 column C, I want the dummy value from Sheet2 column B by matching the Roll number of both sheets, however, I want value only in those rows in which actual value (column B) in Sheet1 is blank.

For reference I am sharing the link of the sheets.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vI22QCmixKe3aoWMLODTFzt7pNXIKO3pjXS4mT6GHT0/edit#gid=524973836

I had checked different question on this community but not found a solution to my query.

Any help on above will really be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: vlookup is a spreadsheet function, you do not need apps script to do vlookup, and there is no such thing as 'vlookup' in apps script, you can make a function work like how vlookup do with apps script, but that is pointless. So question is, what solution are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you want to put down 'dummy values' in Sheet1 column C if column B is empty, and that so call 'dummy value' need to has its 'Roll No.' value matched with the number of the front part of 'Roll No.@Name' column in sheet1:

Solution - 1. in-app lookup function:

[image: sample-1]

- Put this code into Column C2 in sheet1.
- This code lookup for matches of 'Roll No.' from sheet2 column A whenever there Column A is not empty and Column B is empty in sheet1.

```
=ArrayFormula(
 IFS(
  $A$2:$A="","",
  $B$2:$B<>"","",
  TRUE,XLOOKUP(INDEX(SPLIT($A$2:$A,"*"),,1),sheet2!$A:$A,sheet2!$B:$B)
 )
)
```

Solution - 2. write a custom function in apps-script:

in-app call:

[image: sample-2-1]

apps-script js code:

[image: sample-2-2]

- this solution create a custom function called 'MYLOOKUP()' with apps-script, and call the function form the spreadsheet.

```js
// apps-script:

function MYLOOKUP(data1,data2) {
  return data1
    .map(([rollNo_Name,value]) => {
      return (rollNo_Name !== '' && value === '') ?
        data2.find(([rollNo,]) => rollNo_Name.split('*')[0] == rollNo)[1] :
        ''
    });
}
```

in-app call:

```
=MYLOOKUP(A2:B,sheet2!A:B)
```

There are a lot other solution to your question if you mention apps-script, such as...

- instead of calling the custom function in-app, you can instead create a custom menu to run the function when you click on it,
- or add simple trigger so that every time the spreadsheet is edited, the function will be run one time.
- you can even create a web ui for this thing to run, etc.

Comment: @ Ping thanks for your quick solution, I tried the custom function and it is running as expected, however, since it is updated every time a new value in entered in Column A and due to this there is a slight refreshing time. As per the alternate solution offered by you of creating a trigger, I had created a dropdown in Sheet3 so when Refresh is selected in the dropdown the function runs.Can you share your expertise to run the function on dropdown change?