# Vlookup with split text by Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Appscript hence any help on below will be really appreciated.

My query is similar to the one posted in the below link,however, in that question the job is done by custom function and it is working bit slow and runs on every edit. In place of custom function I want to design an Appscript for the same which runs on the change of dropdown.

Link to similar question:

[Google Appscript partial vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74515511/google-appscript-partial-vlookup/74515970#74515970)

Link of sample spreadsheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vI22QCmixKe3aoWMLODTFzt7pNXIKO3pjXS4mT6GHT0/edit#gid=0

Any help on above will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to run the script when the dropdown list of cell "A1" of "Sheet3" is changed to "Refresh".
- You want to obtain the same result with your following script.

  ```
    function MYLOOKUP(data1, data2) {
      return data1
        .map(([rollNo_Name, value]) => {
          return (rollNo_Name !== '' && value === '') ?
            data2.find(([rollNo,]) => rollNo_Name.split('*')[0] == rollNo)[1] :
            ''
        });
    }
  ```

In this case, how about using the OnEdit trigger of the simple trigger? When this is reflected in your sample Spreadsheet, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. When you run the script, please change the dropdown list of cell "A1" of "Sheet3" to "Refresh". By this, the script is run.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet3"; // This sheet name is from your Spreadsheet.
  const { range, value, source } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.getA1Notation() != "A1" || value != "Refresh") return;
  const sheet1 = source.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // This sheet name is from your Spreadsheet.
  const sheet2 = source.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // This sheet name is from your Spreadsheet.
  const range1 = sheet1.getRange("A2:B" + sheet1.getLastRow());
  const obj = sheet2.getRange("A2:B" + sheet2.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, [a, b]) => (o[a] = b, o), {});
  const values = range1.getValues().map(([a, b]) => {
    const temp = obj[a.split("*")[0]];
    return [temp && !b.toString() ? temp : null];
  });
  range1.offset(0, 2, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
  range.setValue(null);
}
```

- In this script, when the dropdown list of cell "A1" of "Sheet3" is changed to "Refresh", the script is run. And, the same result with your script is obtained. And, the value of the dropdown list is changed to `null`.
- The result values are put to column "C" of "Sheet1". If you want to change this, please modify the above script.

#### Note:

- In this script, when you directly run the function `onEdit` with the script editor, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.
- In this script, in order to search the values, I used an object. By this, the process cost might be able to be reduced a little.
- Updated: I reflected `value in to be pulled only when there is no value in Column B`.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @ Tanaike thanks for the excellent solution, the solution works as required except one thing, the script is pulling the value in Sheet1 column C in all the cases, however, value in to be pulled only when there is no value in Column B. Can you please guide how to make this change in the script?

Comment: @Essem Thank you for replying. About `value in to be pulled only when there is no value in Column B`, I reflected it in my proposed sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @ Tanaike thank you for your response, I had tested the result by running the script, it is giving result even when column B has value. It can be checked from the test sheet from below link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vI22QCmixKe3aoWMLODTFzt7pNXIKO3pjXS4mT6GHT0/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Essem Thank you for replying. About `I had tested the result by running the script, it is giving result even when column B has value. It can be checked from the test sheet from below link:`, I apologize for the inconvenience. I have already updated my answer. When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, unfortunately, you have not used my latest script. I think that the reason for your current issue is due to this. Could you please test my latest script in my answer? When I tested my latest script, I can confirm that your expected goal is obtained. I apologize for this.

Comment: @ Tanaike thank you very much for your kind support and excellent solution. The updated script is working perfect.

Comment: @Essem Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.